# Can I capture input text with the P⁣roblem Steps Recorder on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, problem-step-recorder

I have recently been introduced to the Problem Steps Recorder on Windows 7. It's great. Trouble is, it does not recorder keyboard input. When I look at the output of a recording all I see it

> User keyboard input in "Untitled - Notepad" [... Backspace Backspace Backspace Backspace Backspace ...]

So I know the user typed SOMETHING and then deleted five characters. Is there a way to get the PSR to record what was inputted? Or is that a security issue?

This isn't a big deal for notepad, but for custom apps it would be nice to know exactly what a user typed into a text box.